# Error HTTP 500 utilizando HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, vb.net, http, visual-basic-6

Venho aqui pedir um ajuda ao que se refere a requisições HttpWebRequest. Necessito pegar o html de retorno de um error HTTP 500 (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error). Alguém poderia me informar como poderia ser feito?  Abaixo disponibilizo um exemplo de uma requisição HttpWebRequest que está retornando o error

```
 PostData &= "&" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("btnOK", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) & "=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("OK", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

            url = "www.google.com.br"
            req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
            req.Method = "POST"
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "pt-BR")
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie)
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma, "no-cache")
            req.Referer = "www.google.com.br"
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
            req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            req.ContentLength = PostData.Length

        End If

    End If

    Try

        Dim swRequestWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())

        swRequestWriter.Write(PostData)
        swRequestWriter.Close()

        Dim srResponseReader As New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default)

        Html = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd()

        swRequestWriter.Close()

        srResponseReader.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `Catch` do seu `Try`, capture uma `WebException`. A mesma possui diversas informações: resposta(propriedade `Response`), código(`StatusCode`), etc.

Veja a documentação de `WebException`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.110).aspx